# scrapy returns Ignoring non-200 response

Tags: python, scrapy

When I crawl a website with scrapy I got this error message

```
Ignoring non-200 response
```

But when I call the website in browser I got 200 OK

my code looks like this:

```
[..]
      yield scrapy.Request(url=url['name'], callback=self.parse, errback=self.errbacktest, meta={'websiteId': url['websiteId']})

def errbacktest(self, failure):
    print(failure)

    if failure.check(HttpError):
        # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
        # you can get the non-200 response
        response = failure.value.response
        print('HttpError on %s', response)

    elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
        # this is the original request
        request = failure.request
        print('DNSLookupError on %s', request.url)

    elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
        request = failure.request
        print('TimeoutError on %s', request.url)


def parse(self, response):

    print(response.status)
```

What could be the issue in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
yield scrapy.Request(url=url['name'], callback=self.parse, errback=self.errbacktest, meta={'websiteId': url['websiteId']}, headers={('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')})
```

Site was blocking scrapy. Adding a header solved the issue